# my three.js scene is not rendering. not sure why

Tags: javascript, css, three.js

my main.js file contains :-

```
import './style.css';
import * as THREE from 'three';


//create scene
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

//arguments - field of view, aspect ratio, last 2 are view frustrum(controls which objects are visible relative to the camera) 
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  75,
  window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,
  0.1,
  1000,
);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  //which DOM element to use
  canvas: document.querySelector('.canvas'),
});

renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight);
camera.position.setZ(100);


//arguments - radius, widthsegments, heightsegements
const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(15, 32, 16);
//wireframe true to get a better look at its geometry
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffff00, wireframe: true}); 

//torus is creating the mesh with geometry and material //mesh = geometry + material
const globe = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

scene.add(globe);

function animate(){
  requestAnimationFrame(animate); //optimized rendering

  //rotation
  globe.rotateOnAxis += 0.01;
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
animate();

renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

and my index.html :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Gautam</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="globe">This is the canvas
    </canvas>
    <script type="module" src="./main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

All that appears on my screen is :-
[what displays on my browser][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQmJu.png

I checked and my main.js file is definitely executing, but nothing is rendering on the screen

Comment: Any error logs in console?

Comment: no, i checked that as well

Comment: it did give something now
 `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'width')
    at new WebGLRenderer `

Comment: `document.querySelector('.canvas')` is looking for a **class** called canvas...  `document.querySelector('#globe')` is probably what you meant

Comment: it doesnt work even if i use `#globe`, and yes `.canvas` was wrong

Comment: the console error goes away when i use `#globe`

Comment: You don't appear to have a light added to the scene...

Comment: just added this `const light = new THREE.AmbientLight({color:0x404040 }); // soft white light
scene.add( light );` above animation function. Still nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few issues.

```
document.querySelector('.canvas')
```

This would select elements with the *class* `canvas`, but your DOM has no such element.  It does have an element with the *type* `canvas` and the *ID* `globe`, so that line should be one of the following:

```
document.querySelector('canvas')
document.querySelector('#globe')
document.getElementById('globe')
```

Next,

```
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight);
```

As @Mugen87 points out, this should be

```
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
```

As you've written it, the renderer's width is being set to the quotient, and its height (the missing second parameter) is being set to `undefined`, a situation that three.js has no handling for.

And,

```
globe.rotateOnAxis += 0.01;
```

`rotateOnAxis` is a function that takes a vector (the axis of rotation) and a scalar (the rotation angle) as its parameters.  By assigning +0.01 to it, you're simply replacing the function itself, not calling the function.  If, for example, you want to rotate around the globe's y-axis, you could use

```
globe.rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0), 0.01);
```

Finally, the second call to `renderer.render(...)` (the one outside the `animate()` function) is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

> renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight);

Call the method like so instead:

```js
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
```

```js
//create scene
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

//arguments - field of view, aspect ratio, last 2 are view frustrum(controls which objects are visible relative to the camera) 
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  75,
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  0.1,
  1000,
);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  //which DOM element to use
  canvas: document.querySelector('#canvas')
});

renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
camera.position.setZ(100);


//arguments - radius, widthsegments, heightsegements
const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(15, 32, 16);
//wireframe true to get a better look at its geometry
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0xffff00,
  wireframe: true
});

//torus is creating the mesh with geometry and material //mesh = geometry + material
const globe = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

scene.add(globe);

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate); //optimized rendering

  //rotation
  globe.rotateOnAxis += 0.01;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
animate();
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.140.2/build/three.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: this fixed it for me, thanks